# How to set access area using role based for parent and child tables sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: `province` and `fellowships` where each table has different `user role`, province need to be accessed with `super_admin` and fellowship need to be accessed with role `admin` only,
But for province has single user assigned to according to prov_id so different user_admin see separate province and their data. Same to the fellowships.

As shown on tables below, province table is a parent table for fellowships so fellowship is a child table.

```
users
+----------+--------------+
|user_id   | username     |
+----------+--------------+
|1         | josy         |
|2         | jbain        |    
|3         | kibgeza      |
+----------+--------------+

roles
+----------+--------------+
|role_id   | role_name    |
+----------+--------------+
|1         | master       |
|2         | super_admin  |    
|3         | admin2       |
+----------+--------------+

user_role tbl
+-----------+---------+------------+
| user_id   | role_id | access_id  |
+-----------+---------+------------+
|1          | 1       | 0          |
|2          | 2       | 0          |
|3          | 3       | 0          |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

Province(parent table) and fellowships(children table)

```
province tbl
+-----------+---------+------------+
| prov_id   | user_id | name       |
+-----------+---------+------------+
|1          | 1       | ISK        |
|2          | 2       | PIE        |
+-----------+---------+------------+

fellowships tbl
+-----------+---------+------------+
| fellow_id | prov_id | name       |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| 1         | 2       | NDIO       |
| 2         | 1       | OBJ        |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

The problem is on how I can create those user and their access level on the same panel and sql table. I tried to use access_id but seems to have confusion on implementation.
How can I achieve according to this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Sounds like you're NOT talking about database permissions (read, write, delete, alter, ...) on specific tables, but more about web access to run specific queries. Can you give us more info about what you're doing and also what is working? For example, looks like your users can have more than one role. Are you able to query roles for the logged in user?

Comment: True, I'm not talking about roles and permission only but the way to store province(prov_id) per user and fellowship(fellow_id) per user according to role to access. So if role is super_admin means will access province but to extend this by storing prov_id per user_id so user can access a specific province with its prov_id. So different super_admin will see different staff to their province data.

Comment: The same to fellowships one fellowship fellow_id per one admin user_id. I tried to add column to user_role table as access_id, but I think is not correct to be there and will cause an issue later @waterloomatt